# using element_name text in rspec match when_visibile

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a page-object where i define an element as

```
class ProjectCreate
  include  PageObject

  div(:feedback, :class => 'feedback_valid')
  button(:save, :text => 'Save', :index => 0)
 end
```

I'm using rpsec and i'm attempting to wait for feedback_element to be visible and then use the text from the div element in my match.  Here is my test..

```
describe 'Add Project' do
  it 'Provided Form Sucessfully' do
    on(ProjectCreate) do |page|
    page.set_client('add_project/valid')
    page.save
    expect(page.feedback_element.when_present.feedback).to match /Form successfully saved/
  end
end
```

However I'm getting this error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `feedback' for #<Watir::Div:0x3b86f50>
```

I thought that by calling div element by name it would return the text and I could use that in my expect match.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `when_present` method returns the element that it as waiting for. The element does not have the `feedback` method; it is the page-object that does.

You can either get the `text` of the element that is returned by `when_present`:

```
expect(page.feedback_element.when_present.text).to match /Form successfully saved/
```

Or you can wait for the feedback element and then check the value of the `feedback` text:

```
page.feedback_element.when_present
expect(page.feedback).to match /Form successfully saved/
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. You did a really good job of explaining it..  I was a little confuse when looking at the wikin https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Ajax-Calls under the Element level waiting there is an example   @page.foo_element.when_visible.foo

Comment: That example is wrong. It would need to be `@page.foo_element.when_visible.click`. I have updated the example.

Comment: Thanks Justin you are a big help to all of us.